# Merging 2 pandas DataFrames with certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I can't figure out how to merge 2 pandas DataFrames with certain conditions.

I have this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B' ,'B' ,'B'],
                    'Date': ['10/15/2019', '10/16/2019', '10/17/2019', '10/15/2019', '10/16/2019', '10/17/2019'], 
                    'Value 1': [101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203],
                    'Value 2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ,'C'],
                    'Date': ['10/14/2019', '10/15/2019', '10/13/2019', '10/18/2019', '10/18/2019'], 
                    'Value 3': [2, 2, 22, 44, 222]})
```

I need to get to this

[image]

I need merge only names that exist in df1, but add dates that exist in df2. However, those dates should be greater than 10/13/2019.

The closest I could get is

```
df_m = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on=['Name', 'Date'], right_on=['Name', 'Date'], sort=True)
```

But this includes everything ('C' from df2 - I don't need it and date 10/13/2019 for 'B' - I don't need it either).

I'd really appreciate any help.

Edited:
We can drop the condition of dates being greater than 10/13/2019 - I figured this out by just created another df2_mod where I didn't include dates I don't need. However, some dates that exist in df2_mod are not in df1 and I need to merge them with values 3. However I don't need Names from df2 into df1 that don't exist in df1

Comment: Your requirements are unclear.  If you're taking everything from df1 and df2, that's an outer join.  An outer join will always include the 'C' result because it includes everything from both dataframes.  Then if you subset for dates > 10/13/2019, the C result will remain because the date for that record is 10/18.  Either you're describing something not possible, or you need to restate your requirements more clearly.

Comment: So, I need 2 conditions to be met:
1. Merge "outer" but do not include names that don't exist in df1
2. Merge all dates from df2, even if they don't exist in df1.

Comment: I updated my initial question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (I don't filter for dates being greater than 10/13/2019, as stated in the updated question):

1. Fist we filter `df2` and drop all `'Names'` that don't exist in `df1`
2. Do outer join with `df1` and `df2_filtered` on Name and Date columns
3. Sort the values and recreate index

---

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B' ,'B' ,'B'],
                    'Date': ['10/15/2019', '10/16/2019', '10/17/2019', '10/15/2019', '10/16/2019', '10/17/2019'],
                    'Value 1': [101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203],
                    'Value 2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ,'C'],
                    'Date': ['10/14/2019', '10/15/2019', '10/13/2019', '10/18/2019', '10/18/2019'],
                    'Value 3': [2, 2, 22, 44, 222]})

df2_filtered = df2[df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])]       # we want df2 rows with `Names` that exists in df1
print(df1.merge(df2_filtered, on=['Name', 'Date'], how='outer').sort_values(['Name', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Prints:

```
  Name        Date  Value 1 Value 2  Value 3
0    A  10/14/2019      NaN     NaN      2.0
1    A  10/15/2019    101.0      A1      2.0
2    A  10/16/2019    102.0      A2      NaN
3    A  10/17/2019    103.0      A3      NaN
4    B  10/13/2019      NaN     NaN     22.0
5    B  10/15/2019    201.0      B1      NaN
6    B  10/16/2019    202.0      B2      NaN
7    B  10/17/2019    203.0      B3      NaN
8    B  10/18/2019      NaN     NaN     44.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense! I upvoted the answer! This helps me a lot!